# Azure Pipeline Error: Could not find any file matching the template file pattern

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-rm-template

Working on Azure Pipeline as code and trying to create a resource via ARM template in Azure using YAML pipeline.

In Azure DevOps, I have pushed the code (deployment json, parameter json and yml file etc) into Azure Repos Git under a feature branch.

While running the pipeline,  I am facing the error "Error: Could not find any file matching the template file pattern" due to "csmFile" value.

my yml file contains ARM template deployment info as below.

```
    trigger:
 branches:
    include:
    - dev-pipecode

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:

- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'company-development-Contributor'
    subscriptionId: 'XXXXXXXX'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: 'name of the resource group'
    location: 'North Europe'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/AzureAuto/pipelineascode.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/AzureAuto/param-pipelineascode.json'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

Am I missing something? Please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Firstly, just for confirmation.*

Based on this `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/AzureAuto/pipelineascode.json` you defined in the task, you need make sure the location of `pipelineascode.json` in repos should like this:

```
   Repository
    |    AzureAuto
    |    |   pipelineascode.json
    |    |   param-pipelineascode.json
```

Here is the Repository sample of mine:

[image]

---

If the structure of your ARM template repository indeed respect above mentioned, now I guess it should relevant with your branch.

Does your **master** branch still contain `AzureAuto` folder and the `pipelineascode.json`/`param-pipelineascode.json` files?

You can go the `build result` page you encountered the build error message, and confirm whether the branch name is the one you stored the ARM template files:

[image]

As for why I guess so, it is because the system will **build based on master branch by default** while user start with the **new** YAML pipeline and **first** run it.

At this time, you need **copy** the `azure-pipelines.yml` file from `master` branch to that feature branch which stored ARM templates files.

Then go `Pipelines` => Open corresponding YAML build => **Edit** => Focus on upper left corner and change the branch:

[image]

Now, this YAML pipeline should build on the correct branch you stored the ARM templates and succeed to find the JSON file.

Comment: Thanks Merlin for your inputs. 

I removed 'AzureAuto' from csmFile and csmParametersFile arguments and executed the pipeline. It went successfully. Not sure why it does not require specific mentioning of repos name 'AzureAuto'.